# Finding a closer value and copying it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet where it will record payment done in paypal. So basically the users will enter address in all way, so to reduce the errors I have all the possible address the user might enter (This is because this is a payment system for residents in my residential area so I have all the user's address in database). So can anyone help me to find a formula it will find the actual address in "USERNAMES" worksheet and only take the house number and street from the actual data. I have attached some images to explain myself better. I want the formula to be in worksheet "Paypal 2". Please guys I need this help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit#gid=0 - Link to my google sheets

[image: The address entered by users]

```
                        The address entered by users
```

[image]

```
                The sheet to look up for the actual address
```

[image]

```
                   Sheet to split the house number and street
```

Comment: It is not clear where you want the formula(s). Please be specific (sheet name and range) as to where you want formulas.

Comment: @ErikTyler I want the formula to be in PaypalData2 bro (For now I have changed the name into Payment Configuration and I want the formula in Paypal Payment column bro). Do you managed to understand the problem, sorry?

Comment: What is wrong with how you have it now? For what I see you already have the house number and street filled properly.

Comment: @Kessy Yeah it is working bro but sometimes the user might just enter the house number and street without the word bandar puteri or sometimes they would just miss out the coma while typing their address so that is why I am asking help where I have all the actual address since it is a payment project for my residential area. So using the address the user have entered it should be checked with the actual one, and using the actual address it should be sepearted in to house number and column bro. I really hope you can help me with this

Comment: Since you have no control over how users enter their address in PayPal, there is no possible way you can write a formula that will work for every possible variant of entered address. You'll have to manually parse the addresses from PayPal and split it into parts for your records. You could write a regex for the most common way the address would be written (e.g. house #, street name, area) and have try to parse the PayPal address according to that and flag it for your review in the spreadsheet sheet if it fails to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Delete your formulas from 'Payment Configuration'!B3:C3. (This will temporarily remove all results from B3:C.
2. Place the following formula into cell B3:

   `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(PaypalData1!C3:C),PROPER(REGEXEXTRACT(PaypalData1!L3:L, "(\d+)[,\s]+([^,]+\d+)")),))`

`REGEXEXTRACT` allows for extracting more than one grouping, as I've done with this formula; so this should produce a uniform result for B3:C.

The RE2 expression reads "Find the first number(s) followed by any number of commas or spaces and extract the number portion as group one; then find any string after that which does not contain a comma and ends in any number of digits and extract that as group two."